# Extract every other element of a vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

Is there a faster way of splitting a `std::vector` in to two half-size `std::vectors` (one containing values of the odd indices and the other containing values of even indices) than to iterate through the original vector and compare if `index%2==0` for each index?

Comment: I don't know if it would help: have you tried the [`copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)?

Comment: It possible to split it in two passes using a increment of 2 instead of 1, but it will almost certainly be slower than the `% 2` version you already have.

Comment: what is your definition of "better" here? more readable code? faster? less code to type?

Comment: @user1504193 I edited your question to say faster.

Answer (score 18):

I am unsure what is meant by *better* but if C++11 you could use [std::partition_copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) v1.push_back(i);

    std::vector<int> v2;
    std::vector<int> v3;

    bool toggle = false;
    std::partition_copy(v1.begin(),
                        v1.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(v2),
                        std::back_inserter(v3),
                        [&toggle](int) { return toggle = !toggle; });

    std::cout << v2.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << v3.size() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

See online demo http://ideone.com/pa9rW .

Comment: +1 for a simple, clear solution that eliminates any possibility of edge cases on a loop.

Comment: Is it possible to reuse the input range for one of the output ranges?

Comment: @jrok, no that is not possible. From the standard: _The input
range shall not overlap with either of the output ranges._

Comment: I wonder why is that. It's explicitly allowed for `std::transform`.

Answer (score 6):

```
// Make sure the vector is not empty
if(!v.empty()){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < (v.size() - 1); i+=2){
        v1.push_back(v[i]);
        v2.push_back(v[i + 1]);
    }

    if(v.size() % 2) v1.push_back(v.back());
}
```

As noted in the comments by multiple people you have to check that the vector is not empty.  You could avoid the push back calls by resizing both vectors prior to the loop ie.

```
// Make sure the vector is not empty
if(!v.empty()){
    v1.resize((v.size() + 1) / 2);
    v2.resize(v.size() / 2);
    for(size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < (v.size() - 1); i+=2, j++){
        v1[j] = (v[i]);
        v2[j] = (v[i + 1]);
    }

    if(v.size() % 2) v1.push_back(v.back());
}
```

Comment: It is important to note that the vector should not be empty, since in that case the loop condition will fail.

Comment: I don't understand how this is faster than the %2 way... If push_back, i+1 and operator[] are complexity of c each, this would be something like N/2*5c... with %2 looping through every element, wouldn't you have something like N*2c? I guess its possible that operator[] is much faster than the other two, but intuitively that just seems unlikely. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Moritz This way saves both a branch AND a division per iteration so I can easily see it being faster. But as noted, if the size is zero the initial loop will run many iterations.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments I adjusted my answer.

Comment: You can use `.reserve()` and then the `.push_back()` without being afraid of costly reallocations.

Answer (score -2):

old Q by now, but because nobody suggested using iterators and `std::next` yet:

```
// assert myvec.size() % 2 == 0
const unsigned long n = myvec.size() / 2;
std::vector<T> v1(n), v2(n);
std::vector<T>::iterator it = myvec.begin(), i1 = v1.begin(), i2 = v2.begin();
while (it != myvec.end()) {
    v1[*i1] = myvec[*it];
    it = std::next(it);
    i1 = std::next(i1);
    v2[*i2] = myvec[*it];
    it = std::next(it);
    i2 = std::next(i2);
}
```